# Java Strings initials

Tags: java

Can anybody guide me how my output is going out of bounds? What can I do to my method Letters to prevent that out of bound thing? thanks in advance

```
//Something is to be done here to prevent out of bound thing
public class B
{

public String Letter(String List)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for(String s : list.split(" "))
{
    sb.append(s.charAt(0));         
}
return sb.toString();
}
```

Main Method

```
   public static void main(String[] args) 
  {
    Undesired Code Here
  }
```

Answer (score 5):

The issue is here:

```
for(String s : name.split(" "))
{
    sb.append(s.charAt(0));         
}
```

You've been fooled by the example `"thislooks good to  me"`, which contains two spaces in a row. The resulting String between them has a length of `0`, which causes an exception at `charAt(0)`.

Easiest fix is to check for `!s.isEmpty()` before appending.

Comment: Works Perfect. Thanks a ton

Comment: Another way would be using `name.split(" +")`.